# Irreductible polynomial in Q

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, irreducible-polynomials

Hello I got this problem, if $p$ is prime then the polynomial:
$$q(x)=1+x+x^2+...+x^{p-1} $$
is irreductible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. I don't know how to do this exactly. And a problem is that a condition to this question is that I can't use the Eisenstein Criterion, only the basic things about ring theory. 
Thanks if you can help me with this.

Comment: IIRC, Serge Lang's Algebra textbook has a different proof not using Eisenstein's criterion (more useful for proving the general case of cyclotomic polynomials are irreducible, but should also work OK for this case).

Comment: But in this case I cant use Eisenstein... I am looking for other way to do it.

Comment: You can do the same method, and just not refer to the name "Eisenstein". It is completely elementary, and the best way, I think.

Comment: I have no idea, why this marked as a duplicate, when the OP explicitly states, that he does not want to use Eisenstein. You deny someone the chance to give a proof without Eisenstein. There are plenty of them.